# unable to import python modules using jython in java

Tags: java, python, jython, pyarrow

I am using maven and this library to run python file
org.python jython-standalone 2.5.2

and trying to run python file that contains
**import pyarrow.parquet as pq**
and it is giving me error as **ImportError: No module named pyarrow.**

This module is already installed on my local using pip install pyarrow and this file is working fine if it's run through terminal using python.

Comment: PyArrow is compatible with Python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8. This means that it will not work with Jython, where the latest release is 2.7.2. https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html#python-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this web site

https://towardsdatascience.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-apache-arrow-with-apache-spark-and-pandas-bb19ffe0ddae

command for the installation

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow
pip install pyarrow
```